# Twilio + Passing variables into a function

Tags: twilio

I am using the Twillio Studio and have run into a problem I am not sure how to solve

I have these widgets

Gather Input on Call

Which then triggers

Record Voicemail

Which then triggers

A Custom function, which is a Run Function.. I am trying to pass widget variables to it
but I can't seem to work out a way of doing it

When I use the widgets.record_voicemail_1.RecordingUrl ( widget syntax ) as parameters for the function

It is passing the literal strings but not the actual variable values

Can anyone help :) please

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
{{widgets.record_voicemail_1.RecordingUrl}}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will give this a try :)

Comment: it worked, sorry, I don't use stack overflow much.. but worked it out and have accepted your answer :)